# what happen to content when sign an APK?

Tags: java, android

when I'm signing an apk I can view logs like below.

```
  signing: res/drawable-hdpi/abc_text_select_handle_right_mtrl_dark.png
  signing: res/drawable-hdpi/abc_text_select_handle_right_mtrl_light.png
  signing: res/drawable-hdpi/about_logo.png
  signing: res/drawable-hdpi/actionbar_logo.png
  signing: res/drawable-hdpi/active_connections.png
```

So my question is ,

1. if we talk about `about_logo.png` file, what exactly happen to the file after signing? I have checked file size before signing and after signing. size is same.
2. If I read bytes of `about_logo.png` from input stream, is it different than original one?

I have searched on many websites. but couldn't find anything that help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If we talk about about_logo.png file, what exactly happen to the file after signing? I have checked file size before signing and after signing. size is same.

The file is not changed.  The signatures for the files are stored separately. META-INF tree of a signed JAR file has one or more signature files.  These contain the digital signature for each signed file in the JAR.

If you want a deeper understanding, I suggest that you read the relevant parts of the [JAR File Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Signed_JAR_File).

> If I read bytes of about_logo.png from input stream, is it different than original one?

It will be identical to the original file.

---

> I have searched on many websites. but couldn't find anything that help.

General advice: search for the *specification*; e.g. you are looking for a description of how JAR files are signed, so search for `Jar file specification`.